# Nested background processes and SIGINT handling

Tags: bash, sigint

Here is an example script, `simple.sh`, that launches a background process, sends it a signal, and verifies that the signal was handled:

```
#!/bin/bash

function on_signal() {
  echo "1 caught $1, exiting!"
  exit 0
}

function my_sleep {
  trap "on_signal $1" $1
  echo "1 mypid=$$"
  echo "1 mybashpid=$BASHPID"
  echo "1 start sleep"
  for i in {1..10};
  do
    echo "1 sleeping $i"
    sleep 1
  done
  echo "1 failed"
  exit 1
}

signal=SIGINT
if [[ ! -z $1 ]]; then
  signal=$1
fi

my_sleep $signal &
sleeppid=$!
echo ">>> sleeppid=$sleeppid"
sleep 1 # to give script time to run trap
echo ">>> sending $signal"
kill -$signal $sleeppid

for i in 0.25 0.5 1 2; do
  echo ">>> trying $i"
  if kill -0 $sleeppid 2> /dev/null; then
    echo ">>> still running..."
    sleep $i
  else
    echo ">> success"
    exit 0
  fi
done

echo "Failure"
exit 1
```

Now, when I run `./simple.sh`, it works fine. When I run it in the background, `./simple.sh &`, it works fine as well. However, when I add a wrapper, `w1.sh`, that runs `simple.sh` in the background, it suddenly stops working:

```
#!/bin/bash

./simple1.sh $1 &
```

Now `./w1.sh` results in `Failure`. Why?

I have read https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html, and it was very informative, but I still cannot understand how the child process itself can behave differently depending on the *context* it was called in.

Note: I know a "workaround" to get it to behave the way I want to (`w1.sh` should call `(./simple.sh $1) &` in a subshell), but I want to understand what's going on there, and why the workaround works.

Thank you!

Comment: Came from Bazel, that is an interesting find. I tried to compare the `strace -f` output of the workaround and the regular script. I found that the regular script calls `rt_sigprocmask` to block signals to `[INT,CHLD]` just before it catches the signal from `kill`. After digging trough bash code, it might be `readline`'s fault, in some places it just blocks SIGINT. ([example](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/a0c0a00fc419b7bc08202a79134fcd5bc0427071/lib/readline/rltty.c#L611))

Comment: Also, on `zsh` it does not work - even with the workaround.

Comment: Another workaround it to call `/usr/bin/kill` directly. I'm not sure what happened there, but I don't think it is too reliable.